# Confused about my Wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm new to Ethereum and I'm really confused. I am mining to my my Eth address and when I check my address at https://eth.nanopool.org/account/0xADDRESS I see how much ether I have mined so far. But when I check that same address in my GUI wallet on my Linux desktop 'Ethereum Wallet' it's showing 0.00 ETHER. Why is the same address showing 0.00 on the GUI desktop wallet but 0.05....... on the mining pool's website?

I don't remember if I got the address originally from CLI geth, https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info, or the desktop Ethereum Wallet.

Comment: See https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens for further information about accounts/addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The mining pool accumulates the rewards it should pay into your account, and when this amount reaches a predefined threshold, the mining pool will pay that amount into your wallet address.